# Is it possible to access QML anchors from C++?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

When creating QML `QQuickItems` from c++ code, is it possible to access/modify [`anchors`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html)?

All `anchors` properties are declared as `Q_PRIVATE_PROPERTY` in `QQuickItem` and I don't see any method which could help.

Or do I have to implement `anchors` by my own by using signals/events and `QLayout`?

What I would need is for example:

```
Rectangle {
    // ...
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 0
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.rightMargin: -10
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there is a class for anchors. Namely `QQuickAnchors` located in `QtQuick/private/qquickanchors_p_p.h` and handling them belongs to  `QQuickItemPrivate`. But since both classes are not part of the public API, the anwer is: No, you can't access or modify anchors from within C++.

I would consider this good API design rather than a limitation. It forces you to manage visual properties in QML where they belong. So instead of creating QML components from C++ via `new QQmlComponent()`, I would recommend using registered custom types directly in QML (which can be done statically or dynamically with [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) and/or [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) components) from where you have access to the `Item`'s `anchors` and all other visual properties.

Comment: if, as you say, this is "good API design", tell me how I should approach: 1) having to create a QML component with custom properties (I currently inherit QQuickItem to add such properties => C++) and 2) at the same time having to define a custom layout of the QQuickItem - e.g. adding an image achored w/ fill, which is best done from QML

Comment: @Zuzel Well, it's not about "as I say". It's about how Qt decided it from an API design perspective. Honestly, I can't think of any situation where setting layout attributes in QML just isn't enough. If you have a specific issue, go ahead and ask a question

Comment: I thought I just did ask a question and described a specific issue.. Yes, it's their design obviously, and you just said you consider this particular case to be one of the 'good' API design examples. I argued that on the contrary it's an example of _crappy_ API design.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike what the previous answers indicate, it is both possible and has valid use cases. All Qt objects, even the private ones, have introspection APIs. Those APIs what you use from the QML engine. They can be used from C++ too:

```
qvariant_cast<QObject*>(
    item->property("anchors")
)->setProperty("top", otherItem->property("bottom"));
```

Note that there is a race condition because some threads are involved.

QML only supports model lists. Displaying other structures like trees or table is either badly implemented (QtQuickControls 1.x) or mindbogglingly  inefficient (recursive repeaters). For some data structures, C++ is also the only way to implement lazy loading correctly. QML `Loader` go a long way, but not all the way.

Comment: Would you care to share your valid use case? C++ code relying on QML code is not that nice. Although one place where it does make sense is tests.

Comment: Advanced layouts based on `QQuickItem`. QtQuick always assumes the (model) data is a list. Other structures such as tables, charts, graphs, maps and trees are not supported by built-in containers optimizations. Of course, it is possible to represent them anyway, but it doesn't scale. Some layouts like the `ListView` have built in C++ code to optimize lazy/async loading scenarios. This code has to be reproduced to get equivalent performance from other structures. The code has access to the Qt private APIs, ours don't (unless you enable it, but that's far worst than using the introspection API).

Answer (score 1):

For anchors bound to the parent, I found the following as a solution to the "setting `anchors.fill: parent` from c++" problem that arises when you don't have the luxury to instantiate custom types in QML (e.g you have to provide a clean API to create QML objects dynamically):

```
class MyItem : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyItem(QQuickItem* parent){
        if(parent){
            connect(parent, SIGNAL(widthChanged()), this, SLOT(parentWidthChanged()));
            connect(parent, SIGNAL(heightChanged()), this, SLOT(parentHeightChanged()));
            setWidth(parent->width());
            setHeight(parent->height());
        }
        else
            qWarning() << "MyItem must be initialized with a parent.";
    }

private slots:
    void parentWidthChanged(){
        setWidth(parentItem()->width());
    }
    void parentHeightChanged(){
        setHeight(parentItem()->height());
    }
};
```

A similar logic can be followed to emulate `anchors.top`, `anchors.bottom` etc. and associated margins by manual calculation, `setX()` and `setY()` may also be required to achieve this.